# How do I find values that share the same keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want input to be `actorsInCommon(movies, "Moneyball", "Oceans Eleven")`

I want output to be `["Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith"]`

```
movies = {"Moneyball": ["Brad Pitt", "Jonah Hill", "Joe Smith"], 
          "Oceans Eleven": ["Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith", "George Clooney"]}

def find(key, dictionary):
    for (k, value) in dictionary:
        if key == k:
            return value
    return None

def actorsInCommon(dictionary, movie1, movie2):
    movie1Cast = find(movie1, dictionary)
    movie2Cast = find(movie2, dictionary)
    return list(set(movie1Cast).intersection(movie2Cast))
```

Comment: `for k, value in dictionary.iteritems():`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
movies = {"Moneyball": ["Brad Pitt", "Jonah Hill", "Joe Smith"], 
          "Oceans Eleven": ["Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith", "George Clooney"]}
```

Take the intersection of the two sets created form the values in both dictionaries. Use `get()` with a default of an empty list (that will be converted into a set if used) for missing movie names. Convert into a list to match the desired output:

```
def actorsInCommon(dictionary, movie1, movie2):
    return list(set(dictionary.get(movie1, [])) & set(dictionary.get(movie2, [])))

>>> actorsInCommon(movies, "Moneyball", "Oceans Eleven")
['Brad Pitt', 'Joe Smith']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use sets:

```
>>> movies = {"Moneyball": ["Brad Pitt", "Jonah Hill", "Joe Smith"], 
              "Oceans Eleven": ["Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith", "George Clooney"]}    
>>> set(movies['Moneyball']) & set(movies['Oceans Eleven'])
set(['Brad Pitt', 'Joe Smith'])
```

You probably want to change your dict to store the sets themselves so you don't have to keep converting them to sets (note `{}` for set literals):

```
>>> movies = {"Moneyball": {"Brad Pitt", "Jonah Hill", "Joe Smith"}, 
              "Oceans Eleven": {"Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith", "George Clooney"}}    
>>> movies['Moneyball'] & movies['Oceans Eleven']
set(['Brad Pitt', 'Joe Smith'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to check all the values:

```
movies = {"Moneyball": ["Brad Pitt", "Jonah Hill", "Joe Smith"],
          "Oceans Eleven": ["Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith", "George Clooney"]}


print(set.intersection(*map(set, movies.values())))
set(['Brad Pitt', 'Joe Smith'])
```

Or for just the two keys you just need to cast one to a set and use *set.intersection*:

```
movies = {"Moneyball": ["Brad Pitt", "Jonah Hill", "Joe Smith"],
          "Oceans Eleven": ["Brad Pitt", "Joe Smith", "George Clooney"]}


print(set(movies["Moneyball"]).intersection(movies["Oceans Eleven"]))
```